Install replacement rocker panels without welding
2010 Silverado 1500 extended cab 500,000 km
The rocker panels on my truck have rusted out. I have replacement panels (Nor/Am Canada SKU:0897-100L), and I plan to install them with the hope of extending the life of the vehicle.
As a novice with basic skills and tools, are there any issues with my installation plans below?
I want the panels to last for the remaining life of the truck without significant rust: hopefully 5 years, 10,000 km/year, salted roads.

Steps:

Raise the truck using plastic ramps under the front wheels to get some extra space to work under the truck.
Remove the running boards for easy access to the rocker panels.
Cut away the rust using an angle grinder and a reciprocating saw, clean the remaining truck body with brake parts cleaner, and paint with Tremclad Primer.
Before installing, clean the new rocker panels (back and front) using brake parts cleaner and paint using Tremclad Primer.
Since I don't have a welder or autobody experience, I'll affix the new rocker panels to the truck using self-tapping screws and PL Premium construction adhesive.
Paint the installed rocker panels, screws, and construction adhesive using Tremclad White.

I’m not worried about aesthetics.





How bad is the rust under these panels?

If it were me, I'd invest in a cheap welder and do it semi-right. If you leave any rust behind, it's just going to continue to eat away at not only the old metal, but the new metal as well. If you're not worried about aesthetics, your welding/body skills would not be put into question. You should be able to get a decent enough welder for around what the body panels cost you. Just a thought.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Fair point. I’m saving my inevitable deep dive into learning to weld for a long winter and when I have cash to spare for some good quality gear.
